# Inheritable Rake task as a Ruby Gem, in a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Is it possible to write an inheritable Rake task as a Gem such that it works like a framework?

For example, one could build all the logic inside this Rake task and expose some high level callback methods, and developers would implement this callback to run tasks.

The important part here is I'm not asking how to call a rake task from my rails app, but how to write a rake task as a gem, so i could just install the gem in my rails app, and then perhaps I could implement a plain `.rb` file somewhere which gets called by the rake task to handle custom tasks (Instead of the app calling the rake task)

Comment: Are you thinking something like [this](https://andyatkinson.com/blog/2014/06/23/sharing-rake-tasks-in-gems), [this](http://blog.nrowegt.com/building-shareable-rake-tasks-gem/), or [this](https://www.jvt.me/posts/2018/04/05/chef-gem-rake-tasks/)? [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+rake+task+in+gem) might also be helpful.

Comment: Also look at the builder pattern Vlad